# Airflow Snowflake operator tries to execute sql file path as sql statement

Tags: python, airflow

I'm trying to create a SnowflakeOpereator by passing in the path to a sql file.

```
    SnowflakeOperator(task_id="some_task_id",
                      sql='sql/test.sql',
                      **snowflake_connection)
```

However, the operator failed as it tries to execute `sql/test.sql` as an SQL statement, instead of reading the sql file as a templated sql.

I have also tried to create a customised operator inheriting from `BaseOperator` and added the following template fields:

```
    template_fields = ('sql')
    template_ext = ('.sql',)
```

It resulted the same behaviour.

Could anyone advise, please?

Comment: do you really have the backtick in your code \`, instead of the single quote `'`?

Comment: I have tried single quote, double quote and this char

Comment: and the `test.sql` file is in the `sql` directory and Airflow has access to it?

Comment: Yes, same directory as the dag file

Comment: hard to say, if the `.sql` file is inside a subfolder of the dag folder, the only other thing that come to my mind is to see if something modifies the dag `template_searchpath`

Answer (score 1):

Using Airflow 1.10.10, here's an example of using the SnowflakeOperator with passing in a path to the SQL file, as well as making use of the templating feature :)

DAG file *dummy_dag.py*, stored in **dags** folder

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.contrib.operators.snowflake_operator import SnowflakeOperator

dag = DAG('dummy_dag', schedule_interval='0 * * * *', start_date=datetime(2020, 5, 23))

snowflake_operator = SnowflakeOperator(task_id='snowflake_task', sql='./test.sql', params={'dynamic_table': 'my_dynamic_table'},  dag=dag)
dummy_operator = DummyOperator(task_id='dummy_task', dag=dag)

snowflake_operator >> dummy_operator
```

SQL file *test.sql*, stored in **dags** folder

```
SELECT * FROM table;

-- templatised table name using Jinja
SELECT * FROM {{ params.dynamic_table }};
```

In the Airflow UI, if you view the rendered template for the snowflake_task, you should see the SQL that will get executed.

```
SELECT * FROM table;

-- templatised table name using Jinja
SELECT * FROM my_dynamic_table;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I don’t see any difference between your example and my code.

Comment: Hmm, the only difference I can see is that you are using backticks to encase the SQL path, whereas I'm using quotes unless that's just a bad copy-paste?

Also are you able to post a more complete code example? Strange how it works for me & not for you, if we have the same code? Perhaps Airflow version?...

Answer (score 0):

@Lee: not sure if this helps but I believe `template_fields` is a List type. The way you defined it made it a tuple. Not sure if this matters but if you are still stuck, it is worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

if you have multiple lines - it's not working for me

Multiple SQL statements in a single API call are not supported; use one API call per statement instead.
Traceback (most recent call last)